# Override manual Post Deploy Approval in DevOps from within a Release Stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

At the company I work at we use manual post-deploy approvals for deployments in each stage but we'd like to be able to automatically approve a deployment under certain conditions. Updating approvals works great by using 'release/approvals' service of the Devops API but this does not work from within the stage because no approval exists prior to the stage has finished completely.

Are there ways to accomplish this?

Comment: As I understand it, the first part of the story is not really relevant for us. And the second part of the story is: is it possible to implement approval between steps within a given stage? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant!

Comment: Hi @frummel, have you checked my suggestion creating a new pipeline to approve the stage and triggering it via webhook? You can use `filters` in webhook resource to control when the pipeline will be triggered based on the webhook body.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and it worked as described! Thank you for your extensive explanation! I marked your solution as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no default feature that can meet your needs. As a workaround, you can create a new pipeline to approve your stage using REST API [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and trigger this pipeline via a webhook when the statue of the deployment is PartiallySucceeded.

1. Create a webhook and an "Incoming Webhook" service connection.

   To create a webhook, please go to Project Settings -> Service hooks.

- *Trigger on this type of event*: Release deployment approval pending
- *Release pipeline name*: Your target release pipeline
- *Stage name*: The stage used for deployment
- *Approval type*: Post-deployment

[image]

Follow the detailed steps from [Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines) to finish the following steps and create an "Incoming Webhook" service connection.

2. Create a yaml pipeline to run REST API Approvals - Update to approve your stage.

```
    trigger:
      - none
    
    resources:
      webhooks:
        - webhook: pendingapprove          ### Webhook name
          connection: approveSC    ### Incoming webhook service connection name
          filters:
            - path: resource.deployment.operationStatus      ### JSON path in the payload
              value: PhasePartiallySucceeded 
    
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
          $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
          $headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic {PAT}")
          $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/approvals/${{parameters.pendingapprove.resource.approval.id}}?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
          $body = @"
          {
          `"status`": `"approved`",
          `"comments`": `"Good to go!`"
          }
          "@
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

You can get the `approvalId` from `parameters.{webhook name}.resource.approval.id`.